# How to rebalance a dataset based on defined proportions of values across several columns?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a table that looks as follows (example row):

```
|---------------------|------------------|---------------|
|      Color          |       Size       |        Age    |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------|
|       Green         |       Small      |       Young   |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------|
```

The table has thousands of instances with three different colors (green, blue, yellow), three different sizes (small, medium, large), and three different ages (young, middle-age, old).

I also have a set of predefined percentages/proportions for each column. For example:

1. Color:
   30% blue, 40% green, 30% yellow
2. Size:
   25% small, 50% medium, 25% large
3. Age:
   45% young, 45% middle-age, 10% old

My question: How can I create the largest dataset possible that fits the above proportions?

I think that an undersampling technique (i.e. dropping rows with values that are over-weighted) seems to be the path forward, but I'm finding things difficult since each row impacts all three variables I'm controlling for.

The final result would be the largest data-set possible that fits the defined proportions above.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sample each row with probability proportional to the product of the value weights for that row. This is easier to illustrate with an example.

```
N = 100000

# generate N samples of each category; "Color" is sampled non-uniformly to 
# illustrate how to account for prior distribution
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Color': np.random.choice(['blue', 'green', 'yellow'], N, p=[0.9, 0.05, 0.05]),
    'Size': np.random.choice(['small', 'medium', 'large'], N),
    'Age': np.random.choice(['young', 'middle-age', 'old'], N),
})

# target value distribution (e.g., in the final data set, we want 30% blue,
# 40% green, 30% yellow)
target_weights = {
    'Color': pd.Series({'blue': 30, 'green': 40, 'yellow': 30}),
    'Size': pd.Series({'small': 25, 'medium': 50, 'large': 25}),
    'Age': pd.Series({'young': 45, 'middle-age': 45, 'old': 10}),
}
```

First, normalize by the prior distribution. Intuitively, you want to sample with probability proportional to the *ratio* of the target value frequency to the prior value frequency.

```
target_weights['Color'] /= df.Color.value_counts()
target_weights['Size'] /= df.Size.value_counts()
target_weights['Age'] /= df.Age.value_counts()
```

Then, compute the sampling probability for each row.

```
sample_prob = (
    df.Color.map(target_weights['Color']) *
    df.Size.map(target_weights['Size']) *
    df.Age.map(target_weights['Age'])
)
sample_prob.head()
```

```
0    3.354744e-10
1    6.184742e-09
2    3.390995e-10
3    3.396480e-10
4    6.647330e-10
dtype: float64
```

At this point, sampling each row in `df` with probability `sample_prob` will produce the desired distribution. Scaling the sampling probabilities by a constant will still produce the target distribution. In order to get the largest possible sample, ensure that rows with the maximum sampling probability are *always* sampled, i.e.,

```
sample_prob /= sample_prob.max()
```

Then, sample each row with the corresponding probability.

```
df_sampled = df.loc[np.random.random(df.shape[0]) < sample_prob]
```

You can verify the distributions are correct:

```
df_sampled.Color.value_counts(normalize=True)
```

```
green     0.400585
yellow    0.304341
blue      0.295074
Name: Color, dtype: float64
```

```python
df_sampled.Size.value_counts(normalize=True)
```

```
medium    0.497805
large     0.253130
small     0.249065
Name: Size, dtype: float64
```